# SonarQube 6.3: es stops with no obvious failure

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I was trying to bring up a new host for SonarQube. I believe my connections are fine (http get 200 for the desired port). But my es process would quit immediately with below log lines. Can anyone help explaining what might have gone wrong? Appreciate any help!

```
2017.11.01 23:48:52 INFO  es[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting es
2017.11.01 23:48:52 INFO  es[][o.s.s.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9200
2017.11.01 23:48:52 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] version[2.4.4], pid[26917], build[fcbb46d/2017-01-03T11:33:16Z]
2017.11.01 23:48:52 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] initializing ...
2017.11.01 23:48:52 INFO  es[][o.e.plugins] [sonarqube] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.11.01 23:48:52 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [75.1gb], net total_space [78.6gb], spins? [no], types [auto]
2017.11.01 23:48:52 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2017.11.01 23:48:52 WARN  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] max file descriptors [65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
2017.11.01 23:48:53 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] initialized
2017.11.01 23:48:53 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] starting ...
2017.11.01 23:48:53 INFO  es[][o.e.transport] [sonarqube] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}
2017.11.01 23:48:53 INFO  es[][o.e.discovery] [sonarqube] sonarqube/yhMv9glqR6i-TLWARJ2unQ
2017.11.01 23:48:56 INFO  es[][o.e.cluster.service] [sonarqube] new_master {sonarqube}{yhMv9glqR6i-TLWARJ2unQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9200}{rack_id=sonarqube, master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
2017.11.01 23:48:56 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] started
2017.11.01 23:48:56 INFO  es[][o.e.gateway] [sonarqube] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2017.11.01 23:48:58 INFO  es[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
2017.11.01 23:48:58 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] stopping ...
2017.11.01 23:48:58 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] stopped
2017.11.01 23:48:58 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] closing ...
2017.11.01 23:48:58 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] closed
```

Comment: Can you have a look at es.log and web.log ?

Comment: My problem was, the version requires https connection instead of http. From memory ~1month ago, both es.log and web.log don't tell much. The one helped was apache-log, which complained about SSL initiation.

Comment: I don't know how it's possible since TLS connection should be related at all at those issues since it's completely different block (apache Httpd).